# How can two arrays be joined by a common column in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, sorting

I have 2 Pandas arrays like:

```
A = 
        Date       Value
0    2022-03-01     50
1    2022-03-01     50
2    2022-03-03     50
3    2022-03-04     50
4    2022-03-04     50
5    2022-03-04     50
6    2022-03-04     50
7    2022-03-04     50
8    2022-03-15     50
9    2022-03-19     50
10   2022-03-23     50


B =
            Value   Date
Date                                                                             
2022-03-01  0.0   2022-03-01
2022-03-02  0.0   2022-03-02
2022-03-03  0.0   2022-03-03
2022-03-04  0.0   2022-03-04
2022-03-05  0.0   2022-03-05
2022-03-06  0.0   2022-03-06
2022-03-07  0.0   2022-03-07
2022-03-08  0.0   2022-03-08
```

In addition, the A and B lists are of different lengths.

I need to form a list 'C=' in which the dates will go in order (as in the list 'B='), and 'Values' for each date equal the sum of the 'Values' of the list 'A=' for this date...
All 'Values' of the list 'A=' for those dates that are not included in the dates in the list 'B=' should not be in the list 'C='.

I'm new to python
I've tried many options already... But everything doesn't work:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    for n in range(len(B)):
        if A['Date'][i] == B['Date'][i]:
            C['Date'] == B['Date'][i]
            C['Value'] == A['Value'][i]
        else:
            C['Date'] == B['Date'][i]
            C['Value'] == B['Value'][i]
```

The resulting array should be as follows:

```
B =
   Value   Date                                                                             
1  100.0   2022-03-01
2  0.0     2022-03-02
3  50.0    2022-03-03
4  250.0   2022-03-04
5  0.0     2022-03-05
6  0.0     2022-03-06
7  0.0     2022-03-07
8  0.0     2022-03-08
```

/////////
Real arrays are:

```
     Date:           Value:
0   2022-05-06       0.000000e+00
1   2022-05-04      -4.042888e+06
2   2022-04-15      -2.742782e+06
3   2022-04-15      -9.152107e+05
4   2022-04-01      -3.608648e+07
5   2022-04-01      -1.072268e+07
6   2022-04-01      -1.885982e+07
7   2022-04-01      -1.087363e+07
8   2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
9   2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
10  2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
11  2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
12  2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
13  2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
14  2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
15  2022-03-04       0.000000e+00
16  2022-02-03      -4.369548e+06
17  2022-02-01       0.000000e+00
18  2022-02-01       0.000000e+00
19  2022-02-01       0.000000e+00
20  2022-02-01      -3.441539e+05
21  2022-02-01       0.000000e+00
22  2022-02-01       0.000000e+00
23  2022-02-01       0.000000e+00
24  2022-02-01       0.000000e+00
25  2021-11-12      -1.350750e+06
26  2021-11-09       0.000000e+00
27  2021-11-09       0.000000e+00
28  2021-11-01      -3.716895e+06
29  2021-10-19      -2.464551e+07
30  2021-10-15      -5.662351e+06
31  2021-10-15      -1.243596e+06
32  2021-10-01      -4.992055e+07
33  2021-10-01      -2.695814e+07
34  2021-10-01      -2.689851e+07
35  2021-10-01      -2.689851e+07
36  2021-09-26       0.000000e+00
37  2021-09-26       0.000000e+00
38  2021-09-26       0.000000e+00
39  2021-09-26       0.000000e+00
40  2021-09-26       0.000000e+00
41  2021-09-26       0.000000e+00
42  2021-08-24      -7.515941e+08
43  2021-08-20       0.000000e+00
44  2021-08-05      -4.674707e+06
45  2021-08-02      -2.480048e+06
46  2021-05-03      -1.607934e+07
47  2021-05-03      -2.257631e+06
48  2021-04-15      -5.224200e+06
```

```
                        Value:   Date:
Date                                    
2021-11-01                0.0 2021-11-01
2021-11-02                0.0 2021-11-02
2021-11-03                0.0 2021-11-03
2021-11-04                0.0 2021-11-04
2021-11-05                0.0 2021-11-05
...                       ...        ...
2022-05-10                0.0 2022-05-10
2022-05-11                0.0 2022-05-11
2022-05-12                0.0 2022-05-12
2022-05-13                0.0 2022-05-13
2022-05-16                0.0 2022-05-16

[136 rows x 2 columns]
```

After applying the approach described by Nick, all 'Values' in 'C=' are equal to 0.0

```
                Date:               Value:
Date                                    
2021-11-01 2021-11-01                0.0
2021-11-02 2021-11-02                0.0
2021-11-03 2021-11-03                0.0
2021-11-04 2021-11-04                0.0
2021-11-05 2021-11-05                0.0
...               ...                ...
2022-05-10 2022-05-10                0.0
2022-05-11 2022-05-11                0.0
2022-05-12 2022-05-12                0.0
2022-05-13 2022-05-13                0.0
2022-05-16 2022-05-16                0.0

[136 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to inner [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `B` to `A` grouped by `Date` and summed:

```py
C = B.join(A.groupby('Date').sum(), how='inner', lsuffix='_l').drop('Value_l', axis=1)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
                  Date  Value
Date
2022-03-01  2022-03-01    100
2022-03-03  2022-03-03     50
2022-03-04  2022-03-04    250
```

If you want to keep dates from `B` with no sum, use a left join (the default) instead and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with 0:

```py
C = B.join(A.groupby('Date').sum(), lsuffix='_l').drop('Value_l', axis=1).fillna(0.0)
```

Output:

```
                  Date  Value
Date
2022-03-01  2022-03-01  100.0
2022-03-02  2022-03-02    0.0
2022-03-03  2022-03-03   50.0
2022-03-04  2022-03-04  250.0
2022-03-05  2022-03-05    0.0
2022-03-06  2022-03-06    0.0
2022-03-07  2022-03-07    0.0
2022-03-08  2022-03-08    0.0
```

Finally if you want to remove `Date` as the index, use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```py
C = C.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
         Date  Value
0  2022-03-01  100.0
1  2022-03-02    0.0
2  2022-03-03   50.0
3  2022-03-04  250.0
4  2022-03-05    0.0
5  2022-03-06    0.0
6  2022-03-07    0.0
7  2022-03-08    0.0
```

Comment: Nick, look, please... I added the question above

Comment: @Djoe it seems your column names have trailing `:` and space characters on them. If you clean them up the problem should resolve.

Comment: I know, that's why i did: 
C = B.join(A.groupby('Date:').sum(), lsuffix='_l').drop('Value:_l', axis=1).fillna(0.0)

Сould there be a problem in different date formats? 
As far as I understand, in table 'A' the date is in text format...

Comment: And if I use 'C = B.join(A.groupby('Date:').sum(),how='inner',lsuffix='_l').drop('Value:_l', axis=1)' the result is:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Date:, Value:]
Index: []

Comment: @Djoe I'm unable to reproduce your issue, can you take a look at https://ideone.com/9iucHR (which works as expected) and perhaps modify it to be exactly like your data?

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was that in my case: "A = pd.read_excel("A.xlsx ")", the values of the "Date:" column are text...

Comment: @Djoe Ah, probably if you changed them to a date in Excel that might have solved the problem. Anyway, I'm glad you got it working.